# I have no internet after fresh installing 16.04, but it was functional during installation

Tags: ethernet

It's very strange... I can't connect to the internet after installing 16.04 (I dual-boot with windows 10). It was functional during the installation because it installed updates (I also tried installing w/o updates and had the same problem) and I was able to browse the web during the live session. What gives?

My motherboard is the MSI Z97 SLI Plus using the Intel i218v ethernet controller.